# How does a commercial helicopter pilot get a Light Sport Aircraft type rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

I hold Commercial Pilot certification with over 4,000 helicopter pilot in command flight time. What would be my flight training requirements to obtain a type rating for Light Sport Aircraft?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I think your question is essentially the same as [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51862/62); does that help?

Comment: I've added the FAA tag because it seems very likely you're asking about FAA requirements; for questions about regulations etc. please *always* tell us which country or regulator you're asking about. If I got it wrong, you can simply roll back my changes or edit again yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for going to be flying a Rotorcraft category LSA (gyroplane) and you already have gyroplane class privileges, then you already qualify. If you are looking to operate Airplane category SEL class, you need to add those privileges, either with an Airplane PPL or Airplane Sport Pilot aeronautical experience and checkride.

Comment: If he is a rotorcraft pilot but not ASEL he will need more than a checkride.

Comment: That is a good point. I've edited my answer.

Comment: A new checkride (at least with a DPE) is *not* required to add Sport privileges in a new category/class.  See 61.303 and 61.321.  You only need some endorsements from two different CFIs.